# Transform a character column into date

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, date

What is the simplest way to transform the index column from my df to an actual column and then transform it from character to date?

Here is a sample:

```
df <-    
structure(c(" 0.076596889", "-0.004217772", "0.19551752", "-0.11599534", 
    "0.06203595", "0.011884905", "-0.17142789", "-0.04094597", NA, 
    "-0.170884035", "0.14163907", "-0.160324552", " 0.005193002", 
    "0.094337323", " 0.054004389", " 0.342200896", "-0.582262572", 
    "0.99211563", "-1.80983062", "1.56762552", "0.280851484", "-1.04618660", 
    "-0.38132434", NA, "-1.144843376", "0.90148871", "-1.797113427", 
    "-0.604269203", "1.339789966", " 0.103927382", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " 0.141558015", " 0.005554185", 
    "0.32162836", "-0.16310463", "0.09384922", "0.028853136", "-0.29074993", 
    "-0.07721910", NA, "-0.320260458", "0.27066138", "-0.258998975", 
    " 0.022159433", "0.179980305", " 0.092695990", " 0.131799599", 
    " 0.005539599", "0.30970765", "-0.16474883", "0.09485784", "0.029036801", 
    "-0.27107662", "-0.06387477", NA, "-0.271018769", "0.23147817", 
    "-0.219497824", " 0.020039532", "0.154692959", " 0.079533669", 
    "-0.007113455", "-0.338518690", "0.50742611", "-0.29544436", 
    "0.49416319", "0.067917866", "-0.14447349", " 0.19500609", NA, 
    "-0.758730659", "0.45544155", "-0.730001301", "-0.155946684", 
    "0.585023578", " 0.050246438", "-0.007177297", "-0.334579290", 
    "0.50032162", "-0.29218441", "0.48883099", "0.067209227", "-0.14334411", 
    " 0.19332042", NA, "-0.744300043", "0.44290710", "-0.705396078", 
    "-0.149517933", "0.562076971", " 0.048731481", " 0.020630553", 
    " 0.009395069", "0.02771509", " 0.00700098", "0.01903145", "0.009515561", 
    " 0.01362812", " 0.01825617", NA, " 0.009106663", "0.01591710", 
    " 0.007718648", " 0.008820632", "0.007500167", "-0.004636657", 
    " 0.033359185", " 0.020794132", "0.03509503", " 0.01674505", 
    "0.02774480", "0.016422813", " 0.01995413", " 0.02726850", NA, 
    " 0.014408007", "0.02654718", " 0.010979024", " 0.009351808", 
    "0.014444094", "-0.010921319", " 0.159250401", "-0.987571576", 
    "0.75983437", "-2.63835286", "2.19653017", "0.254926885", "-1.00150236", 
    " 0.13780102", NA, "-0.359317531", "0.40311397", "-2.445576883", 
    "-0.351301609", "2.113486497", "-1.003014684"), .Dim = c(15L, 
    10L), .Dimnames = list(c("Retorno do fechamento em 1 dia (de 24Ago20 até 25Ago20) Em moeda orig ajust p/ prov", 
    "Retorno do fechamento em 1 dia (de 25Ago20 até 26Ago20) Em moeda orig ajust p/ prov", 
    "Retorno do fechamento em 1 dia (de 27Ago20 até 28Ago20) Em moeda orig ajust p/ prov", 
    "Retorno do fechamento em 1 dia (de 28Ago20 até 31Ago20) Em moeda orig ajust p/ prov", 
    "Retorno do fechamento em 1 dia (de 31Ago20 até 01Set20) Em moeda orig ajust p/ prov", 
    "Retorno do fechamento em 1 dia (de 01Set20 até 02Set20) Em moeda orig ajust p/ prov", 
    "Retorno do fechamento em 1 dia (de 02Set20 até 03Set20) Em moeda orig ajust p/ prov", 
    "Retorno do fechamento em 1 dia (de 03Set20 até 04Set20) Em moeda orig ajust p/ prov", 
    "Retorno do fechamento em 1 dia (de 04Set20 até 07Set20) Em moeda orig ajust p/ prov", 
    "Retorno do fechamento em 1 dia (de 07Set20 até 08Set20) Em moeda orig ajust p/ prov", 
    "Retorno do fechamento em 1 dia (de 08Set20 até 09Set20) Em moeda orig ajust p/ prov", 
    "Retorno do fechamento em 1 dia (de 09Set20 até 10Set20) Em moeda orig ajust p/ prov", 
    "Retorno do fechamento em 1 dia (de 10Set20 até 11Set20) Em moeda orig ajust p/ prov", 
    "Retorno do fechamento em 1 dia (de 11Set20 até 14Set20) Em moeda orig ajust p/ prov", 
    "Retorno do fechamento em 1 dia (de 14Set20 até 15Set20) Em moeda orig ajust p/ prov"
    ), c("Absolute Hedge Fc de FI Mult", "Absolute Pace Long Biased Fc FIA", 
    "Absolute Svp Prev Fc FI Mult", "Absolute Vertex II Fc FI Mult", 
    "Absolute Vertex S Fc FI Mult", "Ace Capital Fcfi Mult", "Ace Capital S Fc Mult", 
    "Af Invest FI RF Cred Priv Geraes", "Af Invest Geraes 30 FI RF Cred Priv", 
    "Af Invest Minas FIA"))) %>% 
as.data.frame()
```

What I wanted to see was: Row1Col1 = 2020/08/26; Row2Col1 = 2020/08/28; Row3Col1 = 2020/08/31 and so on

Comment: Yeah, I used dput on a dataframe, so i'll just put a %>% as.data.frame in front of the code

Comment: Does these `Retorno do fechamento em 1 dia (de 24Ago20 até 25Ago20) Em moeda orig ajust p/ prov` text in addition to the dates imply the Row1Col1, Row2Col1 etc.  Sorry, I am not familiar with the language

Comment: Yeah. I need to remove the characters to maybe get only '25ago20' and then transform it to as.Date() somehow

Comment: This depends upon your locale settings as well, Do you get NAs for `as.Date('25ago20", "d%b%y")`.  In english settings, it would be `as.Date('25aug20', "%d%b%y")
[1] "2020-08-25"`

Comment: Maybe I have to create a list like "Jan = 01; Fev = 02; Mar = 03..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clean up strings:

```r
ss <- rownames(dd)
## ^ = beginning of string; .* means "string of any characters"
ss <- gsub("^.*até ", "", ss)
## .* = "string of characters"; $ = end of string
ss <- gsub(").*$", "", ss)
rownames(dd) <- NULL
```

Convert:

```r
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "pt_BR.utf8")
dd2 <- data.frame(date = as.Date(ss, "%d%b%y"), dd)
```

My dates are one less than your specified results - they match the ending dates on the strings. You can add one to them if you want to shift them.

(I picked the first Portuguese locale I found: I have no idea if there is a difference between Portuguese and Brazilian date abbreviations??)

Comment: What "^.*" and ").*$" means in this synthax?

Comment: they're matching regular expressions.  I added a little bit of detail.

Comment: made this and got just the result I wanted:

[y <- df

y$Data <- rownames(x)
y$Data <- gsub("^.*até","",y$Data)
y$Data <- gsub(").*$","",y$Data)
rownames(y) = NULL
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","pt_BR.utf8")
y$Data <- as.Date(y$Data, "%d%b%y")
y <- y %>%  select(Data, everything())]

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
# remotes::install_github("vbfelix/relper")
library(relper)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  #Transform data in data.frame
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  # Add rownames as a variable named date
  rownames_to_column(var = "date") %>% 
  # Remove characters from date
  mutate(
    date = relper::str_select(date,after = "\\(de ",before = "\\)")
  ) %>%
  # Separate date into two variables based on the string " até "
  separate(col = date,into = c("date1","date2"),sep = " até ") %>% 
  # Transform those dates from character to date
  mutate(
    across(.cols = starts_with("date"),.fns = lubridate::dmy)
  ) %>% 
  glimpse()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can´t test due to local month name incompatibilites:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
    rownames_to_column() %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    mutate(rowname = str_extract(rowname, "(?<=\\().*(?=\\))")) %>% 
    separate(rowname, c("x", "start", "y", "end"), sep = ' ') %>% 
    select(-x, -y) %>% 
    mutate(across(c(start, end), dmy))
```